# Show that $Per_n(f)$ of periodic points of period $n$ is finite

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Prove that if $f: X \rightarrow X$ is an expansive topological dynamical system of a compact dynamical system $X$, then the set $Per_n(f)$ of periodic points of period $n$ is finite.

Any ideas of how to approach this question?

Could strong hints be given please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: suppose $x$ is an accumulation point of $Per_n(f)$.  What can you deduce?

Comment: That it has a convergent subsequence to some point in $Per_n f$ as in compact space?

Comment: Is $x$ in $Per_n(f)$?  If so, can $f$ be expansive?